# Trying to get a function to work using pointers

Tags: c

This is a problem from my course lesson where we are learning C-language. Why do I get the error below? I tried to search it on Google and I couldn't find anything. The error is not especially helpful with the info provided as I can't change the line it references.

```
main.c:21:14: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
   21 |    isChanged = AdjustState(waterTemperature, &waterState);
      |              ^
```

For the lesson I am not allowed to change the main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
  
void AdjustState(int waterTemperature, char* waterState) {
   if (waterTemperature < 100) {
      *waterState = 'L';
   }
   if (waterTemperature < 100) {
      *waterState = 'G';
   }
}

int main(void) {
   int waterTemperature;
    char waterState;
   bool isChanged;

   waterState = 'B';
   scanf("%d", &waterTemperature);

   isChanged = AdjustState(waterTemperature, &waterState);

   if (isChanged) {
      printf("Water state is changed to %c.\n", waterState);
   }
   else {
      printf("Water state %c is not changed.\n", waterState);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `The error is not especially helpful with the info provided as I can't change the line it references.` The error says the function returns nothing (`void`), you can't store nothing in a variable.

Comment: *The error is not especially helpful with the info provided as I can't change the line it references.* - the error message is very helpful if you understand what it says. It tells you, that you are trying to us a return value of a function defined as `void`. So don't define it as `void` if you can't change the line itself!

Answer (score 2):

You should change the return type of the function `AdjustState` and have it return something that fit to the function `main`.

It looks like it should return if the function changed the value pointed at by `waterState`, it can be like this:

```c
int AdjustState(int waterTemperature, char* waterState) {
   char originalWaterState = *waterState;
   if (waterTemperature < 100) {
      *waterState = 'L';
   }
   if (waterTemperature < 100) {
      *waterState = 'G';
   }
   return *waterState != originalWaterState;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function has the return type `void`

```
void AdjustState(int waterTemperature, char* waterState) {
   if (waterTemperature < 100) {
      *waterState = 'L';
   }
   if (waterTemperature < 100) {
      *waterState = 'G';
   }
}
```

Thus this statement

```
isChanged = AdjustState(waterTemperature, &waterState);
```

is invalid. A function with the return type `void` returns nothing.

If you may not change the function declaration then you should write for example

```
waterState = 'B';
char currentWaterState = waterState;

scanf("%d", &waterTemperature);

AdjustState(waterTemperature, &waterState);

isChanged = currentWaterState != waterState;

// ...
```

Also it seems that there is a typo within the function

```
   if (waterTemperature < 100) {
      *waterState = 'L';
   }
   if (waterTemperature < 100) {
      *waterState = 'G';
   }
```

The both if statements have the same condition expression. Check the conditions and change one or them.

Maybe you need to write something like the following

```
void AdjustState(int waterTemperature, char* waterState) {
   if (waterTemperature < 100) {
      *waterState = 'L';
   }
   else  {
      *waterState = 'G';
   }
}
```

Or alternatively

```
void AdjustState(int waterTemperature, char* waterState) {
   *waterState = waterTemperature < 100 ? 'L' : 'G'; 
}
```